# Using spring validations : Message not been returned in restful service containing @valid and validation annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, validation, microservices

Rest service :Spring boot, Postman, Tomcat, maven are the technologies and tools I am using to validate the data : I am expecting some message in the postman response. Can you please suggest me what could be the changes that I have to Make sure in the below code.

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/requestShipment")
    @Validated
    public class ShipmentRequestController {
    
        @GetMapping
        public String requestShipment(@Valid @RequestBody  ShipmentRequest shipmentRequest) {
            System.out.println("helloo");
            return "Sampleclass";
        }
        
        /*
         * @PostMapping(value="/sampleclass") public @ResponseBody void
         * requestSampleClass(@Valid @RequestBody SampleClass sampleclass) {
         * 
         * }
         */
        
        @GetMapping(value="/sampleclass")
        public String requestSampleClass(@Valid @PathParam("data") @NotNull String data) {
            return data;
        }
    }
    
    Postman request : (according to the request, last method will be called)
    http://localhost:8080/requestShipment/sampleclass
    Result I am getting from postman :
    
    {
        "timestamp": "2020-10-24T06:27:07.376+00:00",
        "status": 500,
        "error": "Internal Server Error",
        "message": "",
        "path": "/requestShipment/sampleclass"
    }
    
if you could observe in above response,  message attribute is null
Expected result : message had to be written. something like " requestSampleClass.data: must not be null"
    
    Error in the Spring boot console :
    javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: requestSampleClass.data: must not be null
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:116) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at com.rakuten.shipment.controller.ShipmentRequestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e373f1a4.requestSampleClass(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

`@PathParam` is not a valid Spring annotation, and so Spring isn't filling in that value. I'm not sure what dependency you're adding that supplies it, but you may be mixing systems. (You *also* don't have any placeholders in the path, so it doesn't make sense at all.) I think you want `@RequestParam` instead.

Comment: You mentioned "there are no place holders in the path" : thats what i am validating the data with out passing anything in the URL. (from the postman).

what dependency: <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
   </dependency>

@RequestParam : its not working even i kept the same.. let me know if you have other thoughts. thanks.